# How do I use multiple source files in Free Pascal on the command-line?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

How do I compile a Free Pascal program consisting of multiple source files?
Specifically, is there a Makefile-like system for Free Pascal?

Comment: You don't need it. Pass search directories and the main file to pascal, and the compiler will do the rest. Pascal has a fully developed Module system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is by using a `uses` clause in the preamble of your program to import units from another file.  See the [Free Pascal Language Reference](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/ref.html) for a description of the langauge supported by Free Pascal.

Comment: How do I make a unit? Do I have to compile all the units in my program every time I build a program, and if so, what is the easiest way to include them in other units or the main file?

Comment: "How do I make a unit?"  Start by reading item 16.2 et seq of the FPLR.  If you don't have an FPC IDE like Lazarus, you can use your favourite text-file editor.